# Entity Framework database first duplicate foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

I'm using database-first EF 6 model generation (`.edmx` file).

My tables are:

**User**:

```
UserID - int
UserName - string
```

**Note**:

```
NoteCreatedByUserID - int ( fk )
NoteModifiedByUserID - int ( fk )
NoteDeletedByUserID - int ( fk )
NoteMessage - string
```

When I generate the model from the database, the object in code allows me to call it by : `Note.User` or `Note.User1` or `Note.User2` and I cannot tell which column it is mapping to..

Is there a post-edmx generation script that I can run (or bundle into the generation) that will allow me to change the name of these to something more useful e.g. `Note.UserCreated`, `Note.UserModified` and `Note.UserDeleted` ?

Thanks

Comment: In the edmx designer, right click the navigation property and rename it

Comment: Right click the nav property -> properties -> You can see the association, "From Role" "To Role"

Comment: Other than manually changing your `.edmx` model - no, I couldn't find anything (for the exact same issue). There *is* a chance you could modify the T4 templates that generate the `.edmx` model and code - but I gave up after a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a post-edmx generation script that I can run

No.

The "generate EDMX from database" process is not functionally equivalent to writing things by hand.

For this you need to manually edit the EDMX. And remember not to replace that entity from the database.

(You could use a manually written partial file to wrap a better named property around the generated partial class, but that assumes the names are stable, but I've never seen that guaranteed: eg. a naming change to a FK could easily chance the ordering.)